# How to recuperate end date and start date value from a Time Line slicer and put them into cells

Tags: excel, vba

Please I need Help to recuperate in a timeline  slicer, end date and start date values in order to put them in cells and do seceral opérations on it ( duration interval).

Comment: Can you please explain your problem further so that we can better understand the scenario ?

Comment: @KarthickGanesan I Already have a timeline slicer. and for some specifics operations I need to get this timeline slicer value and affect them into cells. everay time i'll change the end date en start date on this slicer, values in the corresponding cells should change automaticaly or by using a macro.